# ARP-Scan / aNmap alternatives on Android?

Tags: networking, mac-address

Are there alternatives for these utilities on Android that can be invoked using shell commands? I need to fetch a list of connected hotspot devices, the only method I have is to flush the ARP cache and fetch the new list by invoking `arp -n`. Which isn't that accurate anyways.
What others ways could I approach this? aNmap didn't work for me, it simply listed nothing about the clients with either -sn or -sP switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) for linking me to the solution. [Original response by Squidly.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/113090/squidly) The solution was to use `ip neigh show dev <interface>` if you're rooted.

If there are active clients you should get something like this -

[image: output]

In case the clients aren't active and you're looking this up for OUI lookup purposes, I also added `grep -i -e reachable -e delay | grep -o ' ..\:..\:..'` to filter them.